# Showing FontAwesome Icons on Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, text, font, icon, unicode

I can't show these icons from FontAwesome:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ]
        , target: 'map'
        , controls: ol.control.defaults({
            attributionOptions: {
                collapsible: true
            }
        }), //Vista inicial del mapa
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-5.9334, 43.5848])
            , zoom: 15
        })
    });
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject, {
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            })
        })
        , style: new ol.style.Style({
            /*image: new ol.style.Circle( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} ({
                radius: 20
                , fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#000000'
                })
            }))*/
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                text: '\uf041'
                , font: 'normal 38px FontAwesome'
                , fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#ff0000'
                 })
            })
        })
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

Does anybody use typographic icons as Openlayers icons?
I need help...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to look at [the existing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932615) on parent forum website StackOverflow

You may prefer using `ol.style.FontSymbol` from [ol-ext project](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/style/map.style.font.html)

Comment: can you give an exemple with maki2?

Comment: Please read and follow the answers. The second link of my answer redirects to a solution where Maki2 is supported... Can't do more, sorry.